# Is Powerball QuickPick Onto?

Tags: probability, statistics

Currently, there are ${69 \choose 5} \times {26 \choose 1}$ combinations for the powerball. That's a lot of combinations.  While we do not know precisely how the quick pick mechanism works, let us assume (to make this problem interesting), that a $2^{32}$ number is used to seed the random number generator which produces the quick picks. In fact, $\frac{{69 \choose 5} \times {26 \choose 1}}{2^{32}} = 0.06$. Thus its certainly possible for the quick pick mechanism to be surjective, but is it? What is the expectation on the number of valid combinations which cannot be obtained via quick pick?

Comment: If we don't know how the quick pick generator works, how can we answer this question?  You have shown that it may be onto.

Comment: I specified poorly.  I meant to assume that it is a function with 2^32 inputs each of whom produces an output identical to picking the lotto numbers from the cage.

Answer (score 1):

There are ${69 \choose 5}26=292\ 201\ 338$  valid combinations.  If you generate $2^{32}$ quick picks, the chance that a given combination is not generated is $\left(1-\frac 1{292201338}\right)^{2^{32}}\approx 4.1348\cdot 10^{-7}$.  You would expect about $292201338\cdot 4.1348\cdot 10^{-7} \approx 120$ of the combinations not to be generated.